# Why do my 2D objects not collide in Unity despite that the layers are set correctly?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a platform that I need to flip the direction of when it collides with an object. The platform as well as its child objects belong to the layer "FlyingOrPlatform". The object that the platform collides with should belong to the "GameControl" layer. But if i set it to that it doesnt collide with it.

If I set the object that the platform collides with to either the "Player" or "Default" layer. Then it works completely as it should. But I wish to use the "GameControl" layer.

I have tried where I save the scene and the project, as well as restarting the editor.

I dont see what should be wrong with my layer setup. Any suggestions?

In my script for reversing the platform direction there is no layer check, it does check the tag but I ensured that the tag is the same when I switch between the layers. I just use Unity's built in OnTriggerEnter2D lifecycle method. Have tested with OnCollisionEnter2D and OnTriggerStay2D as well, same result.

Here is a link to a video demonstrating the issue, as well as a screenshot of my physics2D settings below. In the video I first show how its supposed to work, and then I switch the object the platform collides with to the GameControl layer, after which it doesnt work.

Video of issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-eqYI-K-Ug

Physics2D settings:
[image]

Comment: From what I can tell this appears to be an issue with the Physics2D matrix in Unity that occurs from time to time. A couple of other people have written similar things on other forums.

Comment: For lack of better, I found a work-around by using the "Ignore Raycast" layer instead of the "GameControl" layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell this appears to be an issue with the Physics2D matrix in Unity that occurs from time to time. A couple of other people have written similar things on other forums.

Among others [this reply](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1557529/2d-collision-matrix-not-working.html) had a similar issue:
[image]

For lack of better, I found a work-around by using the "Ignore Raycast" layer instead of the "GameControl" layer.

I have reported it as a bug to Unity.

EDIT:

Here is the reply I got from Unity.

> "Hi,
>
> We successfully reproduced this issue. It will be possible to follow
> the progress on a chosen resolution in our public Issue Tracker once
> the report has been processed (this might take up to an hour):
> https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/product/unity/issues/guid/1325018
>
> We highly appreciate your contribution. If you have further questions,
> please feel free to contact us."